# Cannot parse object because no supported Content-Type was not specified in response. Content-Type was 'text/html;charset=utf-8'

Tags: spring, rest, web-services, junit, spring-test

I'm trying to run the following Junit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfig.class, Account.class, AccountDao.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class AccountTest{


    private static final String URL_PREFIX = "http://localhost:8080/dsp2api";
    private String cookie;

    private RequestSpecification givenAuth() {
        // return RestAssured.given().auth().form("user", "userPass", formConfig);
        // if (cookie == null) {
        // cookie = RestAssured.given().contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").formParam("password", "userPass").formParam("username", "user").post(URL_PREFIX + "/login").getCookie("JSESSIONID");
        // }
        // return RestAssured.given().cookie("JSESSIONID", cookie);
        return RestAssured.given()
            .auth()
            .basic("user", "userPass");
}
    @Test
    public void whenMethodArgumentMismatch_thenBadRequest() {
        Response response = givenAuth().get(URL_PREFIX + "/api/foos/ccc");
        ApiError error = response.as(ApiError.class);

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, error.getCode());
        assertEquals(1, error.getErreur().length());
    }

}
```

But when I do, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot parse object because no supported Content-Type was not specified in response. Content-Type was 'text/html;charset=utf-8'.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping.deserialize(ObjectMapping.groovy:82)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping$deserialize.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.as(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:216)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.as(RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.java:159)
    at com.app.dsp2api.test.AccountTest.whenMethodArgumentMismatch_thenBadRequest(AccountTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

The ErrorApi I'm basing my test on is this one:

```
public class ApiError {

    private HttpStatus code;
    private String erreur; 
    private String description;

    public ApiError() {

    }

    public ApiError(HttpStatus code, String erreur, String description) {
        this.code = code;
        this.erreur = erreur;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public HttpStatus getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(HttpStatus code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getErreur() {
        return erreur;
    }

    public void setErreur(String erreur) {
        this.erreur = erreur;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    } 


}
```

And Here's my exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(
      MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, HttpHeaders headers, 
      HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        String error = ex.getParameterName() + " Requête invalide";

        ApiError apiError = 
          new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,ex.getLocalizedMessage(), error );
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getCode());
    }

}
```

What I would like to know now is where can I specify the content-type (json) so that this error disappears?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE 1**:

Changed the following line:

```
Response response = givenAuth().get(URL_PREFIX + "/api/foos/ccc");
```

To:

```
Response response = givenAuth().log().all().header("ContentType","application/json").when().get(URL_PREFIX);
```

But it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This should be an issue with your url. Either the service is not available or the service url is wrong. Try triggering the same request with POSTMAN to confirm there is no issue with your request and service.